# Handle a database crash in the application level

Tags: java, database, exception, crash

Question is pretty clear and Ill set an example.

(Read this:)
Lets say we have an application in the user's machine and a remote Database. The application is highly dependent on the database to retrieve stuff according to user's selections.

Which are the approaches to handle a database crash/internet disconnection etc.?

One would be to show a message when an attempt to connect to the DB occurs but then what? 
Shut down the application or is it possible to disable it for lets say one minute and retry
connecting during this period and if it fails then force shut it down again?

Comment: it's up to your users.  you could have a retry message, y/n

Comment: This question is impossible to answer, since it is completely unclear what context your application is operating in and why the impossibility to connect to a database should be a reason for shutting the system down?

Comment: I dont get how you are getting confused about the context... its a standard application with a remote database...

Also, where did I talk about shutting the system down? I was talking about shutting down the application and obviously the user should have to restart it. Moreover, the app. would check the DB availability at its start-up.

EDIT: Plus it doesnt have to do with a specific language or DBMS, its a general architectural question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poll your database/internet connection for availability, and if its unavailable do as @Beth stated and notify your users.

If the issue is an internet connectivity or DB issue, restarting the application isn't likely to fix anything, and is more likely to annoy your users and they will think restarting the application is a resolution.

A solution I use for a network connected application is to poll connectivity intermittently and display the connectivity status for the user to view. The same can be done with your database.

Granted you will have additional overhead as a result of continual checks, but if your connection is less then stellar it may be a solution that works for you.

As an aside, if your database is crashing on a consistent basis (or enough to warrant it being mentioned in this question) you should really consider either another host, or review your configuration and fix that issue, databases are built to be robust...

Comment: Fair answer, I guess I just wanted to hear that from someone else too. Thanks!